# How to add LINQ Results to List

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

```
DataTable dt = GetData(txtZip.Text);
List<Entity> objlist = new List<Entity>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Entity obj = new Entity();
    obj.Zipcode = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
    obj.FacilityName = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    obj.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
    obj.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[3]);

    objlist.Add(obj);
}

var result = objlist.GroupBy(member => member.Zipcode)
                    .Select(group => new
                    {
                        Zipcode = group.Key,
                        Latitude = ,
                        Longitude = ,
                        FacilityName = string.Join(",", group.Select(m =>    m.FacilityName))
                    }).ToList();
```

I want to add result to List,like this `objList.Add(result)`
and before that what i added to list will be overwrite with this statement
and how to get Latitude and Longitude

Answer (score -1):

Apparently I had misread or misunderstood the question initially.

> I want to add result to List,like this objList.Add(result) and before that what i added to list will be overwrite with this statement and how to get Latitude and Longitude

In order to add multiple items to your already existing list without overwriting what is in there, use the

```
objlist.AddRange(_someIEnumerableOfT_)
```

instance method.

> and how to get Latitude and Longitude

As you have grouped your entities by zipcode, you will most likely have multiple entities per zip code. Your select statement operates over each group - a key, and an IEnumerable of items that share that key. It is unclear which of these values you would want to use, but assuming an average is sufficient for your use, the following code would do what you need.

- You were creating a new anonymous type, whereas you most likely wanted your original type.
- By assigning the result to the original list, you would be left with the one Entity per ZipCode that I believe was the original intention.
- You could replace the Average method call below with "First().Latitude" if you were only interested in a value. As GroupBy guarantees no empty groups, you should never run into a case where First() throws an exception.

```
objlist = objlist.GroupBy(member => member.Zipcode)
                .Select(group => new Entity
                {
                    Zipcode = group.Key,
                    Latitude = group.Average(m => m.Latitude),
                    Longitude = group.Average(m => m.Longitude),
                    FacilityName = string.Join(",", group.Select(m => m.FacilityName))
                }).ToList();
```